# Is there a repository of credentials used in training materials/samples and SDKs?

Tags: passwords, appsec, default-password

Similar to a default password list for network appliances, it's conceivable that application layer passwords are default from training materials given to a developer.

In fact, I have discovered applications that have an authentication system largely unchanged from the corresponding SDK.

Is there a repository of usernames, passwords and even private keys & certificates that are given to users when following an online training, or similar SDK?

Comment: I'm not aware of a specific repo. for this, but to be honest googling <product or SDK name> default credentials generally does the job just fine...